# What is this bond notation?

Tags: bonds

I'm taking practice exams for the SIE and along came this question:

The last transaction in XYZ 5.50s 2030 was at 102. This bond is selling at:

Answer: a premium.

I understand the basics of bonds (I think), but the textbook I used while preparing for the exam never used this notation, and I'm having trouble formulating a useful search query. Can someone please explain what's going on here? Thanks.

Comment: Related: [What does it mean “Cudahy Packing Company 5s, due 1946”?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/131975/what-does-it-mean-cudahy-packing-company-5s-due-1946)

Answer (score 3):

> The last transaction in XYZ 5.50s 2030 was at 102.

- "XYZ" is the issuer.
- "5.50" is the coupon.
- "s" means semiannual coupon payments.
- "2030" is the maturity.
- "102" is the last trade price.

The bond was sold at $102, which is above par ($100), so the bond sold at a premium.

Comment: Thank you! Is there meaning to the "s" in "5.50s"? Semiannual?

Comment: @PintoBox Yes. I've added it into the answer.