# What does it mean "Cudahy Packing Company 5s, due 1946"?

Tags: bonds

I was reading a bond description from "Security analysis" and found this excerpt "Cudahy
Packing Company First Mortgage 5s, due 1946." Can some one explain me please the meaning of this sentence. I understand "Cudahy Packing Company" is the name of the company and they have issued a 1st Mortgage bond, what I didn't understand is last words i.e. "5s, due 1946".

EDIT 1: Updated question as per suggestion.

Comment: What country are you in / the bond from? If it's India, then since it will have been pre-independence, it _may_ be that bonds were denominated in British currency, in which case **5s** would be **5 shillings** (where there were 20 shillings to the pound). Also, you have **1938** in your title, and **1946** in the question... you might want to [edit] to make them consistent.

Comment: @TripeHound It is an American corporate bond. [Cudahy Packing Company](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cudahy_Packing_Company).

Comment: Why do you have "Rail Road Bond 5s" in the title, but "Cudahy Packing Company First Mortgage 5s" in the body?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take an example — "XYZ Widget Corporation 5s, due 2030":

- "XYZ Widget Corporation" is the issuer name.
- "5" is the coupon rate.
- "s" means semiannual coupon payments.
- "2030" is the maturity year.